# If I sleep with Lae'zel, am I locked out of romancing someone else?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

During Act 1, when I went to dismiss Lae'zel from the party, the conversation took a sudden turn when she bluntly asked if I wanted to sleep with her. If I say yes, am I locked into a relationship with Lae'zel? Will this lock me out of romancing other party members?

[image: Lae'zel wanting to sleep with me]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not. In general, it is possible to abort the romance plotline with most companion characters through a "break up" dialog option that is almost always available when talking to them. Afterwards you are able to pursue a relationship with any other companion, provided that it is still early enough in the game's story for the relevant relationship event triggers to occur.

There are a couple exceptions, though. For example, the relationship with Astarion becomes permanent if:

> the player decided to let him ascend after defeating Cazador and then decides to become Astarion's vampire spawn.

There are also a couple situations that allow to romance multiple characters at the same time (and no, that's a feature and not a bug). However, as far as I could find, Lae'Zel isn't a part of any of those poly-romance routes.

Oh, and no matter who you are romancing, you will be able to cheat on them with

> Mizora, your spirit guardian, the drow prostitutes in Sharess' Caress and/or Raphael's minion Harleep.

Will you get away with that?

> Nah, not spoiling that :)

Comment: What does "early enough in the game's story" mean? Should break ups be done before moving on to Act 2?

Comment: @Stevoisiak That depends on who you intend to romance. If you have questions about the key trigger moments of a specific companion romance, I would recommend that you ask a new question. But one important storypoint that appears to set off multiple romance plots is the celebration after saving the Druid grove.

Answer (score 3):

You are not locked into a relationship with Lae'zel if you accept her advances.

Though I believe if you refuse her here, you will lock yourself out of further romance with her down the line.